# How to take json input and do simple calculation and return value using Flask

Tags: python, json, api, rest, flask

The API input is like

```
{
  "Fruits": [
    {
      "name": "Apple",
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": 24
    },
    {
      "name": "Banana",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 17
    }
  ],
}
```

when we give this JSON input to the API it has to calculate the order and
The response should be like

```
{'order_total':41}
```

Comment: what have you tried? please provide [mcve]. Is it possible there are other values that need to be calculated like Vegetables?

Comment: Seems like you already managed to calculate the order total by hand. What do you need our help figuring out?

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(fruit["price"] for fruit in fruit_dict["Fruits"])
```

if you want it in a result dict:

```
result_dict = {}
result_dict["order_total"] = sum(fruit["price"] for fruit in fruit_dict["Fruits"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake in order total.

```
import json


json_raw = """
{
  "Fruits": [
    {
      "name": "Apple",
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": 24
    },
    {
      "name": "Banana",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 17
    }
  ]
}

"""


data = json.loads(json_raw)
print(data)

total = 0
for fruit in data ["Fruits"]:
        total += fruit["quantity"] * fruit["price"]

print(f"Total : {total}")

order = {}
order["order_total"] = total

print(f"Generated json:{json.dumps(order)}")
```

Here the output that i got

```
nabil@LAPTOP:~/stackoverflow$ python3 compute-total.py
{'Fruits': [{'name': 'Apple', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 24}, {'name': 'Banana', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 17}]}
Total : 65
Generated json:{"order_total": 65}
nabil@LAPTOP:~/stackoverflow$
```

Comment: I think the `price` is the price of 2 apples, not every apple.

Comment: Not sure that's why i suggest